Windhawk changing close button hover colour
I have been trying to change the window's close button hover colour. I have had DLL issues and unexpected results, such as transparent windows and crashes. I can't seem to get this idea to work. My last attempt is below, which currently makes windows invisible and unclickable. There have been issues with dwmapi.dll.
// ==WindhawkMod==
// @id              close-button-hover-color-changer
// @name            Close Button Hover Color Changer
// @description     Attempts to change the close button's hover color safely on Windows 11
// @version         2.0
// @author          AssistantModder
// @github          https://github.com/AssistantModder
// @include         *
// @compilerOptions -ldwmapi -luser32 -lgdi32
// ==/WindhawkMod==

// ==WindhawkModReadme==
/*
# Close Button Hover Color Changer

This mod attempts to safely customize the hover color of the close button across applications that use the Windows DWM API, specifically tailored for Windows 11.

## Features
- Attempts to change the hover color of the close button.
- Safe approach to avoid unintended side effects.
- Detailed logging for troubleshooting.

Note: This mod is experimental and may not work for all applications or Windows versions, especially modern UWP apps in Windows 11.
*/
// ==/WindhawkModReadme==

// ==WindhawkModSettings==
/*
- closeButtonHoverColor: "#FF6666"
  $name: Hover Color
  $description: Color when hovering over the close button (e.g., #FF0000 for red, #00FF00 for green).
- enableMod: true
  $name: Mod Enabled
  $description: Toggle the mod on or off.
- logLevel: 4
  $name: Logging Level
  $description: Set logging level - 0:None, 1:Error, 2:Warning, 3:Info, 4:Debug
*/
// ==/WindhawkModSettings==

#include <windows.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Structure to hold the mod's settings
struct ModSettings {
    COLORREF hoverColor;
    BOOL enableMod;
    int logLevel;
} settings;

// Function prototype for the DWM API call
typedef HRESULT (WINAPI *DwmSetWindowAttributeFptr)(HWND, DWORD, LPCVOID, DWORD);

// Original function pointer
DwmSetWindowAttributeFptr DwmSetWindowAttribute_Original;

// Converts a hex string to COLORREF
COLORREF HexStringToCOLORREF(const wchar_t* hexColor) {
    unsigned int r, g, b;
    if (hexColor && wcslen(hexColor) == 7 && swscanf(hexColor, L"#%02x%02x%02x", &r, &g, &b) == 3) {
        return RGB(r, g, b);
    }
    Wh_Log(L"Error: Invalid hex color format '%s'. Using default red.", hexColor);
    return RGB(255, 0, 0); // Default to red on failure
}

// Custom logging function based on the log level
void CustomLog(int level, const wchar_t* format, ...) {
    if (level <= settings.logLevel) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        wchar_t buffer[256];
        vswprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(wchar_t), format, args);
        va_end(args);
        Wh_Log(L"%s", buffer);
    }
}

// Hook function for DwmSetWindowAttribute to change close button hover color
HRESULT WINAPI DwmSetWindowAttribute_Hook(HWND hwnd, DWORD dwAttribute, LPCVOID pvAttribute, DWORD cbAttribute) {
    if (settings.enableMod && pvAttribute && cbAttribute == sizeof(COLORREF)) {
        COLORREF* colorPtr = (COLORREF*)pvAttribute;
        COLORREF originalColor = *colorPtr;

        // Log only the close button hover color attribute
        if (dwAttribute == DWMWA_CAPTION_BUTTON_BOUNDS) { 
            CustomLog(4, L"DwmSetWindowAttribute: Attribute %d, Original Color: 0x%06X", 
                      dwAttribute, originalColor);
            *colorPtr = settings.hoverColor;
            CustomLog(4, L"DwmSetWindowAttribute: Attribute %d changed from 0x%06X to 0x%06X", 
                      dwAttribute, originalColor, settings.hoverColor);
        }
    }
    return DwmSetWindowAttribute_Original(hwnd, dwAttribute, pvAttribute, cbAttribute);
}

// Load settings from the Windhawk mod settings
void LoadSettings() {
    settings.hoverColor = HexStringToCOLORREF(Wh_GetStringSetting(L"closeButtonHoverColor"));
    settings.enableMod = Wh_GetIntSetting(L"enableMod") != 0;
    settings.logLevel = Wh_GetIntSetting(L"logLevel");
    CustomLog(3, L"Settings loaded: HoverColor=0x%06X, EnableMod=%d, LogLevel=%d", 
              settings.hoverColor, settings.enableMod, settings.logLevel);
}

// Initialization function for the mod
BOOL Wh_ModInit() {
    LoadSettings();

    HMODULE dwmapiModule = GetModuleHandle(L"dwmapi.dll");
    if (!dwmapiModule) {
        dwmapiModule = LoadLibrary(L"dwmapi.dll");
        if (!dwmapiModule) {
            CustomLog(1, L"Failed to load dwmapi.dll module");
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    DwmSetWindowAttribute_Original = (DwmSetWindowAttributeFptr)GetProcAddress(dwmapiModule, "DwmSetWindowAttribute");
    if (!DwmSetWindowAttribute_Original) {
        CustomLog(1, L"Failed to get DwmSetWindowAttribute function address");
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (!Wh_SetFunctionHook((void*)DwmSetWindowAttribute_Original, (void*)DwmSetWindowAttribute_Hook, (void**)&DwmSetWindowAttribute_Original)) {
        CustomLog(1, L"Failed to set hook for DwmSetWindowAttribute");
        return FALSE;
    }

    CustomLog(3, L"Mod initialized successfully");
    return TRUE;
}

// Function called when the mod settings are changed
void Wh_ModSettingsChanged() {
    LoadSettings();
    CustomLog(3, L"Settings reloaded");
}

// Uninitialization function for the mod
void Wh_ModUninit() {
    CustomLog(3, L"Mod uninitialized");
}


Why are you altering the caller's input value on a SET operation, instead of altering the output value of a GET operation? The caller is trying to save a new attribute value to DWM, not retrieve one. Perhaps you meant to hook DwmGetWindowAttribute() instead?
In any case, inside of your DwmSetWindowAttribute_Hook(), you should not be dereferencing pvAttribute until you first check dwAttribute to find out what type pvAttribute points at.  You are unconditionally dereferencing pvAttribute as a COLORREF for every attribute that just happens to be the same size as a COLORREF (4 bytes), but that is no guarantee that pvAttribute actually points at a COLORREF.   For example, many of the defined attributes use BOOL (4 byte) values.
Case in point - in your code, if (dwAttribute == DWMWA_CAPTION_BUTTON_BOUNDS) will always be false, because pvAttribute points at a RECT (16 bytes) for that attribute, not a COLORREF.
DWMWA_CAPTION_BUTTON_BOUNDS is for getting/setting the dimensions of the caption buttons, not their colors.  AFAICS, there is no DWM attribute defined for button colors.

Thanks for the feedback. I've implemented the suggestions:

Hooked DwmGetWindowAttribute
Checking for DWMWA_CAPTION_COLOR

Issues persist:

Entire title bar color changes, not just close button
Windows sometimes become transparent

Questions:

Correct attribute for close button hover in Windows 11?
Cause of transparency issue?
Alternative approaches for Windows 11 UI customization?

Any further guidance appreciated.

Per the documentation, there is no DWM attribute for getting/setting any color of any button on the titlebar. DWMWA_CAPTION_COLOR is for the titlebar itself.
